# Distribution of $\frac{n}{2}$ red and $\frac{n}{2}$ blue balls in $B$ boxes of $S$ slots each.

Tags: probability, statistics

I have got $n$ balls, and $B$ boxes. Each box $B$ has $S$ slots, where $S \ll n$. Now assume $\frac{n}{2}$ balls are red in color, and the remaining $\frac{n}{2}$ balls are blue in color. If a machine shoots the $n$ balls in those $B$ boxes, and the probability of each ball landing in any of the $B$ boxes is the same, then what can we say about the distribution of the red and blue balls in those boxes, for these cases:

- $B \le \frac{n}{2}$
- $\frac{n}{2} < B \le n$
- $B > n$

It can be safely assumed that $B * S \ge n$. Can we quantify the number of buckets with only red balls, only blue balls, and a certain mix of both the balls?

Comment: Does the number of slots have anything to do with how many balls can be in one of the boxes? If it does, how do we reconcile that effect with the statement that the probability of each ball landing in any of the boxes is the same?

Comment: I apologize @David. This is a formulation of the model of a real problem I have. I fixed the question. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of balls in any given box follows a [Hypergeometric Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Your question is not entirely clear about what exactly you want. Section 7.1 of [this](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shuchi/courses/787-F09/scribe-notes/lec7.pdf) gives a lot of things you can do with the balls and the boxes.

For example, without loss of generality assume you distribute the blue balls first. The expected number of empty bins is $\left(1-\frac{1}{B}\right)^\frac{n}{2}$ - this is the expected number of bins with no blue balls. Similarly it is also the expected number of bins with no red balls. The expected number of bins with no balls at all is  $\left(1-\frac{1}{B}\right)^n$. So, the expected number with only blue (or red) is $\left(1-\frac{1}{B}\right)^\frac{n}{2}-\left(1-\frac{1}{B}\right)^n$.